# Como remover um usuário do servidor?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, servidor

Utilizo um servidor com Ubuntu e instalei o Git para compartilhar código remotamente.

Criei um usuário Git com o comando:

```
$ sudo adduser git
```

Qual comando devo utilizar para remover um usuário?

Comment: Já tentou `sudo userdel userName`? [Fonte](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-remove-user-command/)

Answer (score 3):

O `userdel` serve pra isto:

```
$> sudo userdel git
```

Se quiseres remover a pasta *home* do usuário, use a opção `-r`

```
$> sudo userdel -r git
```

---

- [Man page do Ubuntu sobre este comando](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/userdel.8.html).